# Using PATCH to modify multiple entries with node/mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to send my node server multiple entries in order to update every person inside the database.

I thought a way to do it would be to loop through each person through their unique Ids and save the updated information based on this.

However, inside the Employee.findById function I cannot access the value of `[i]` so I cannot get the relevant employee. Running this line of code when trying to modify 2 Employees `var i` will output;

[image]

```
router.patch('/edit', function(req, res, next) {

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {

        console.log("outside " + i)

        Employee.findById(req.body[i].employeeId, function(err, employee) {

            console.log("inside " + i)

        /* 
            employee = new Employee({
              name: req.body[i].name,
            })

            employee.save();
        */


        })
    }

})
```

I'm not sure why the `console.log("inside " + i)` isn't outputting the same number as the outside log?

Also, I'm not sure if the approach I am taking is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `/edit` route is called, the for loop runs, logs out the `"outside"` statement and calls the `Employee.findById` method for each element in `req.body`, which will execute and call the `"inside"` console log statement **when the find operation has finished**. *Note that this is an asynchronous operation.*

The `i` variable does not change inside the callback of the `Employee.findById` call. This is because the for loop already incremented `i` to the number of elements in `req.body`.

By doing this, you will not be able to tell if all operations finished or an error occured while saving the employee documents and forward this information to the client in the response.

I would suggest using [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) or another flow controll library.

Your example using `async`:

```
router.patch('/edit', function(req, res, next) {
    async.each(req.body, function(obj, cb) {
        Employee.findById(obj.employeeId, function(err, employee) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }
            employee = new Employee({name: obj.name});
            employee.save(cb);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        // any errors from callback will be handled here
        // inform you user in the response or whatever
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! - Just to note in my case creating a new employee will not work as we have to modify the existing one, so to get the code to work I had to simply replace that code with `employee.name = obj.name`. ( Of course this was not part of my original question, but just thought I would add it in just in case it might help someone else )

Answer (score 1):

It's because the function `findById()` is **asynchronous**. The iteration of the loop doesn't wait `findById()` terminated the query. 
I suggest you in order to fix this problem to use the lib [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async).
It's provide some useful methods for doing things in asynchronous and wait the response.
In your case something like that can fix the problem:

```
async.each(req.body, function (value, callback) {
    Employee.findById(value.employeeId, function(err, employee) {
        employee = new Employee({
          name: value.name,
        })
        // The callback indicate that this iteration is terminated.
        employee.save(callback);
    });
}, function (err) {
    // When all callback() are triggered we pass here, and this tells we finished all operation.
});
```

I suggest you to read carefully the documentation of [`each`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

Comment: asyncs `eachOf` and its alias `forEachOf` iterate a collection. The code example shows that req.body is an array.

Comment: Note that `employee.save()` is an async operation too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will have to take the time to look over the whole async library now